# Docker general configuration

Tags: docker, window

For my personnal developping environement, I'm trying to learn docker and the best pratices for good configuration. But now I have à lot of question about how docker is working.

I'm on windows then I'm using hyper-v for running MobyLinuxVM, first I would like to know if it's possible to connect my-self to the VM to see what is inside and what is used for. Secondly I would like to know what this VM is used for? Is it for the deamon? Thirdly I would like to know where the daemon is set (wath is running) then what is the job of the service com.docker.service? Finaly is there a way by commande line to show the actual deamon ip and port and an example to show how the docker cli is connecting to?

Thanks, if someone is able to help me, because I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: MobyLinuxVM is there for Linux containers in Linux container mode. You shouldn't need to connect to it directly, just work with containers, but if you want, here's how: https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/ssh-into-docker-vm-windows/ . If you work with Windows containers, the VM is not needed. The daemon must be running anyway (the _dockerd_ process). It may be installed as a service with _dockerd --register-service_. IP and Port is set by you if you enable _tcp_ socket, e.g. _dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375_. Then you can use e.g. _docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 ps_ to access daemon remotely.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the link. That is exactly what I was looking for.